# HTML: liking resources (stylesheets / scripts) that require Windows Authentication

Tags: html

I have a situation where, in an HTML page, I have these two resources in the `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://some-server.local/styles.css">
<script src="https://some-server.local/script.js"></script>
```

For reasons that are unfortunately beyond my control, the linked resources in question require Windows Authentication to be accessed. In other words: the browser will prompt me with a popup asking for user/pass if I try to go to those addresses directly, as in the following screen:

[image]

However, if I just put the tags in the head like shown above, the browser will NOT show the authentication popup, it will simply fail.

Is there a way I can link those resources and force the browser to show the authentication popup?

Comment: Add credentials to url `https://administrator:passwordOfAdmin@some-server.local`

Comment: @Justinas: Thanks, but I don't want to hard-code the credentials in the page code... I want the user to provide his own credentials when he connects to the page

Comment: Well, these resources should not be behind authorization

Comment: @Justinas: I know, I know, but as I said in the question: unfortunately this is beyond my control, so I was wondering if there was some kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tests, I concluded that browsers actually **do** ask for credentials if you link resources that are behind Windows Authentication. I don't know why it didn't work before, maybe there was something wrong with my html. So basically, what I wanted to do is already implemented.